# Out Of Memory Exception in WinForms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I created a TaskBar application in Visual Studio which minimizes itself inside the system tray and show notifications to the user based on the database change. Whenever a new task assigned to the user he will notified at the system tray like a balloon popup. But whenever the applications runs for an average 15 hours time suddenly my applications crashes and shows out of memory exception. So i have some questions please answer them.

1. How can i debug this issue ? I can't wait for 15 hours and check for this issue ?
2. Is there any tool available to check the memory leakage of my application which can directly point at my issue ?
3. How can i generate out of memory exception to my program so it will be debugged easily and fast ?
4. What should i do to avoid memory leakage in my code ?

Image of my application : [image]

Comment: I assume that as you are catching the error then you know in which block of code this error occurs? Can you post that code as there may be something obvious.

Comment: Hello Matt thanks your reply.... but in each and every method i added try... catch... finally block in my code and after executing my program it dosen't crashes directly... but it need some time to crash that the reason i wrote average time to crash is 15 hours.... yesterday i started my application and today i saw the error....

Comment: @Rick Jackson: As Matt eluded, since you are catching the exception already, it should be relatively easy to determine which block of code it's coming from.  Display the entire stack trace in your error message.  This will tell you exactly what call triggered the exception.  Also, log it to a file.  Then, you can view it even after stopping the program.

Comment: @NYSys ok.... Can you tell me how can i display the entire stack trace in my error message so i could figure out what call triggered the exception....

Comment: Standard answer: use a memory profiler.

Comment: @Rick: See Matt's response below to display the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can examine the stack trace as follows (posted as an answer so it would format correctly):

```
Try
    Dim s As String = "1234".Substring(3, 5) 'some code that throws an exception
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error: " + ex.Message + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + "Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
End Try
```

Comment: It's a little shorter if you just call ex.ToString() which will include the message and the stack trace.

Answer (score 7):

In response to your 4 questions:

1: You can intercept the [My.Application.Startup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4zch4d2%28VS.80%29.aspx) event to add some exception-handling code. Note that the code for the Startup event handler is stored in the ApplicationEvents.vb file, which is hidden by default. Here is some C# code (almost identical in VB) that will setup your exception handlers:

```
// Event handler for handling UI thread exceptions.
Application.ThreadException += 
    new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(App_UiThreadException);

// Force all Windows Forms errors to go through our handler.
// NB In .NET 4, this doesn't apply when the process state is corrupted.
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

// Event handler for handling non-UI thread exceptions. 
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new 
    UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(App_NonUiThreadException);

// Run the application.
```

2: You can use the free [CLR Profiler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/archive/2011/02/01/clrprofiler-v4-released.aspx) to check memory usage.

3: You can throw the [OutOfMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception.aspx) exception yourself if you want to see how your program will handle it.

4: One useful resource is [Debug Leaky Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163491.aspx). Another one is [Identify CLR Memory Leaks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318263).